# pip ERROR: Invalid requirement: '==' in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install a specific version of the albumentations library by doing:

```
!pip install albumentations == 0.4.6
```

and I get this really weird error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '=='
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pip install albumentations==0.4.6
```

Without space :)